# Powershell get-childitem output formatting

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

**How can I change the formatting of powershell output?

I am running this:**

```
cgi -Recurse K:\AppData\*.* -Filter *.model | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending >> C:\AAA\result.txt
```

**The result I got is in this format:**

```
Directory: K:\AppData\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-a---        13/02/2014  11:29 AM    7269129 20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart 
-a---        13/02/2014  11:29 AM    7269129 20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart 
-a---        13/02/2014  11:29 AM    7269129 20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart
```

**How can I change the output format to this :**

```
LastWriteTime           Name                                  Directory
-------------           ----                                  -----
 13/02/2014  11:29 AM   20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart     K:\AppData\
 13/02/2014  11:29 AM   20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart     K:\AppData\
 13/02/2014  11:29 AM   20-300_3001_REV02_ECR4431.CATPart     K:\AppData\
```

Answer (score 8):

I know the usual answer is, don't use the format-* cmdlets, since the output can't really be used by other cmdlets, but since this a **formatting** question, how about something like:

```
get-childitem -Recurse K:\AppData\*.* -Filter *.model | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | format-table LastWriteTime, Name, Directory >> C:\AAA\result.txt
```

The only downside I can see is if the directory name ends up being too long, you may need to try playing with adding either `-Wrap` or `-AutoSize` to the end of the format-table cmdlet.

If neither of those solves the width issue (assuming you even have one), I found a (page)[http://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/] about creating really wide tables, so you could end up with something like:

```
get-childitem -Recurse K:\AppData\*.* -Filter *.model | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | format-table LastWriteTime, Name, Directory -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 1024 >> C:\AAA\result.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can re-order the properties with `Select-Object` (select):

```
gci -Recurse K:\AppData\*.* -Filter *.model | 
? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | 
sort LastWriteTime -descending |
Select LastWriteTime,Name,Directory
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, but it wont work.....I tried select-object already.... the resault still the same....

Comment: Can you post the script where you trid that?  I've never seen that not work.

Comment: I tried the same code you post above, it gave me the same result . the format wont change at all. I am thinking I may have to use css file to work with it which i dont want to make it too complx......

Comment: I can't reproduce that result.

Comment: The select worked for me on my box, although the directory got truncated since I was using a longer path as my test...

Comment: If it's truncated, that the defalt format-table doing that.  Try piping the result through format-list, or format-table -autosize